# How to post an answer to this question

Tags: discussion, support, answers, community-wiki, historical-lock

How can I add my answer to the following question?

[**Hidden Features of SQL Server**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121243/hidden-features-of-sql-server?page=3&tab=votes#tab-top)

The question is about the hidden features in SQL Server. Now I have a trick to give alias name to subquery columns. This trick is not present in existing answer

Here is the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 1,'a',NULL,NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1,NULL,'d',NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1,NULL,NULL,'c'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1,NULL,'d',NULL) a (groups, a, b, c)
```

How do I add this as an answer to the above mentioned question or can a moderator add this answer?

Answer (score 13):

Did you read the post notice?

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed

This sort of question was once askable, and answerable on Stack Overflow - it no longer is (due to changing community standards), and as such new answers cannot be added.

Also, this question belonged on [Stack Overflow meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) as it is specific to that site, not to the network in general - which is what this meta is.